# Can't remove "http://gatheringpoint.com/*" from chrome's notifications settings

Tags: google-chrome

I don't know this website but I can't remove it from the list of allowed notifications in "chrome://settings/content/notifications".

I removed 2 others but I don't know this website and can't remove it. I click on the "..." next to it, then "Remove" and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, this may be something pre-installed with Chrome.

Regardless, if you cannot remove it, you should still be able to block it. [Per Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

- On your computer, open Chrome.
- At the top right, click More More and then Settings.
- At the bottom, click Advanced.
- Under "Privacy and security," click Content settings.
- Click Notifications.
- Choose to block or allow notifications then "Block a site". Next to "Block," click "Add" and enter the site, then click Add.

"You can also block any sites, apps, and extensions that already have permission to send you notifications. Just click Manage exceptions."

---

If you're still having issues, you may wish to try one or more of the following:

1. Remove any possible offending Chrome Apps. These can create entries which cannot be modified due to notification integration.
2. Similarly, you may wish to doublecheck any extensions installed.
3. [Reset your browser settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2765944?visit_id=637601752567685231-129716211&p=chrome_cleanup_tool&rd=2).
4. Completely reinstall Chrome.

Comment: Can't block it either. tried adding "http://gatheringpoint.com/*" to the blocking list and it does nothing. same for "gatheringpoint.com/*". could only add "gatheringpoint.com/" without the last asterisk (*), which won't help much... Any more insights?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with "http://iblogbox.com/devtools/myjson*" that I want to remove from the list of enabled notifications. I can't do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer. Basically, everything solvable I read about this issue revolved around Chrome hijacking the ability to modify these settings because they were tied to Chrome Apps. So that's where I would look next, along with extensions. I also included a link to a recommended Google tool but I can't speak to its effectiveness. As a last resort, I suggest completely removing and reinstalling (but that's pretty drastic).

Comment: You should probably travel into your settings like once a month (or whenever things change) - there's lots of stuff in there you may not be aware of.

Anyhow, took me forever to find but chrome://apps for finding and removing apps.

I went so far as to search in the profile folder for references to the stuff I couldn't delete - which it looks as if stuff just gets left in there...so maybe a way to get everything you care about *out* of your chrome profile is worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "chrome://apps/" and remove any apps, that you don't use. It will make your "chrome://settings/content/notifications" look much cleaner.